Sharepoint Azure AD certificate authentication in Java
I need to access Sharepoint through a Java app using Azure AD certificate authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread). The equivalent of this C# sample:
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using PnP.Framework;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace AzureADCertAuth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var authManager = new AuthenticationManager("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "certpath.pfx", "password", "foo.onmicrosoft.com");
            using (var cc = authManager.GetContext("https://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"))
            {
                cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = cc.Web.GetFileByUrl("https://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/docpath.docx");
                ClientResult<Stream> streamResult = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                cc.ExecuteQuery();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(streamResult.Value))
                {
                    string fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This C# code is working fine for accessing Sharepoint, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it in Java.
I tried something like this
import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;
import com.azure.core.http.HttpClient;
import com.azure.core.http.HttpMethod;
import com.azure.core.http.HttpRequest;
import com.azure.core.http.HttpResponse;
import com.azure.core.http.okhttp.OkHttpAsyncHttpClientBuilder;
import com.azure.identity.ClientCertificateCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SharepointTest {

    public static void getAccessTokenCert() {
            ClientCertificateCredential credential = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder().clientId(
                            "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                    .tenantId("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111")
                    .pfxCertificate("certpath.pfx", "password")
                    .build();
            
            AccessToken token = credential.getToken(new TokenRequestContext().addScopes("https://foo.sharepoint.com/.default")).block();
            
            String url = "https://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/docpath.docx";
            HttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpAsyncHttpClientBuilder().build();

            HttpRequest request = null;
            try {
                request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethod.GET, new URL(url)).setHeader(
                        "Authorization", "Bearer " + token.getToken()).setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request).block();
            String responseBody = response.getBodyAsString().block();
    }
}

But requesting the token throws the following exception:
throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/codec/DefaultHeaders$ValueValidator
Any ideas what I need to do differently?

You may be missing some dependency or you could have two different versions of netty classes in you classpath.

Hi @K.Oja Any update?

I have one file named sri.docx in my SharePoint site with below content in it:

Initially, I registered an Azure AD application and granted 'Sites.FullControl.All' SharePoint permission of Application type:

Now, I created one client certificate and uploaded it to above app registration like this:

In my case, I used below sample code snippets to access SharePoint like downloading file through Java application with Azure AD client certificate authentication.
AuthManager.java:
import com.azure.identity.ClientCertificateCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class AuthManager {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "appId";
    private static final String TENANT_ID = "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    private static final String CERTIFICATE_PATH = "C:\\test\\sricert.pfx"; // Path to your .pfx certificate file
    private static final String CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD = "password"; // Password for the .pfx certificate
    private static final String SCOPE = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/.default";

    public static String getAccessToken() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ClientCertificateCredential credential = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .tenantId(TENANT_ID)
                .pfxCertificate(CERTIFICATE_PATH, CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD)
                .build();

        TokenRequestContext request = new TokenRequestContext().addScopes(SCOPE);

        AccessToken token = credential.getToken(request).toFuture().get();
        return token.getToken();
    }
}

SharePointClient.java
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SharePointClient {
    private static final String SITE_URL = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sritestsite";
    private static final String FILE_RELATIVE_URL = "/sites/sritestsite/sridoclib/sri.docx"; //Your file's relative URL

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String accessToken = AuthManager.getAccessToken();
            // Print the access token
            System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);

            // Fetch file content
            byte[] fileContents = fetchFileContent(accessToken, SITE_URL, FILE_RELATIVE_URL);
            saveToFile(fileContents, "downloaded_file.docx");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] fetchFileContent(String accessToken, String siteUrl, String fileRelativeUrl) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(siteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + fileRelativeUrl + "')/$value");
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            return inputStream.readAllBytes();
        }
    }

    private static void saveToFile(byte[] content, String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            fos.write(content);
            System.out.println("File saved successfully: " + filePath);
        }
    }
}

Response:

When I checked the downloaded file, it has same content as SharePoint file like this:

Before running the above code, make sure to install required dependencies in your Java project:
pom.xml:
<dependencies>
        <!-- Azure Identity for Authentication -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTP Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

